# Quaternion orders such that every proper ideal is invertible

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, quaternions

Let $B$ be a quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\mathcal{O} \subset B$ be an order.

A lattice in $B$ is *(left) proper* over $\mathcal{O}$ if its left order is equal to $\mathcal{O}$.  We say $\mathcal{O}$ is *good* if every lattice in $B$ proper over $\mathcal{O}$ is invertible (equivalently, locally principal; equivalently, projective as a left $\mathcal{O}$-module).

How do you classify good quaternion orders $\mathcal{O}$?

If you ask only for containment--i.e., every lattice in $B$ with $\mathcal{O}$ contained in the left order is invertible--then you have the hereditary orders.  <strike>If I haven't made a mistake, then there are Gorenstein orders that are not good.</strike>

I'm asking because every quadratic order has this property: every lattice in a quadratic field is invertible over its multiplicator ring--and this plays an important role in the theory of complex multiplication.  I'm curious to see how far this holds for quaternions.

Any thoughts would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Juliusz Brzezinski pointed me to his paper "Riemann-Roch theorem for locally principal orders" (http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01456982): he calls these orders "locally principal" and in Example 2.6(b) he explains that locally principal orders are equivalently Gorenstein orders.